# issue in locating cx_oracle python package files/directory

Tags: python, pycharm, cx-oracle, python-packaging

I installed `cx_Oracle` `python` package using `pycharm's` package installer. It installed successfully and also works perfectly. The installed directory for the package is shown as `c:\program files(x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\`. When I go to this directory I do not see the package directory for `cx_Oracle`. I only see following two related to `cx_Oracle` - `cx_Oracle-6.0.1.dist-info` directory and `cx_Oracle.cp36-win32.pyd` file. For other packages I see package directory as well as a info directory but for `cx_Oracle` I see only the info directory.

Where does the package directory for cx_Oracle is present?

Answer (score 1):

file cx_Oracle.cp36-win32.pyd is the cx_Oracle module itself. When You imports cx_Oracle in Your Python program, Python interpreter loads this pyd (which is de facto a dll library linked against python36.dll) and calls functions from this Python "module". cx_Oracle has no more files (ie cx_Oracle.py(o|c)) like other modules.

Comment: So all the functions like cx_Oracle.makesdn() and so on are implemented in this `pyd` file?

Comment: Yes. You may try this in Python console:

import cx_Oracle

dir(cx_Oracle)


and you see what is in this module.